# Update Textbox in VBA automatically when other Textbox is filled

Tags: vba, ms-word

I want to automatize a simple code in a Microsoft Word VBA Macro.

```
Private Sub TextBox2_Change()
TextBox2.Text = TextBox1.Text
End Sub
```

Right now, the number of TextBox1 in TextBox2 is displayed only when I click on the Textbox2 in my document and then hit any key.
My goal is that changes that are made in TextBox1 automatically get transferred to TextBox2.

Thank you in advance

Comment: What issues are you having?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My goal is that changes that are made in TextBox1 automatically get
>   transferred to TextBox2.

Therefore you need to capture changes made in `TextBox1`, not `TextBox2`.

```
Private Sub TextBox1_Change()
    TextBox2.Value = TextBox1.Text
End Sub
```